# Does dynatrace monitor oracle ebs(11i) completely?

Tags: oracle11g, dynatrace

I want to monitor oracle ebs(11i) & oracle db(11g) simultaneously during load test through dynatrace.
[Oracle EBS architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1oam.png)

1. I know we can monitor oracle db using dynatrace but did not find how to Identify what areas or modules (e.g. Order Management, Sales, Finance, Shipping) a particular work flow/user request touches during the load test?
2. I found that using DC RUM we can capture the metrics for Form Server. Apart from this I also want to monitor Concurrent processing server. Is it possible using dynatrace or not?

Answer (score 0):

With Dynatrace DC RUM you may choose one of two approaches of monitoring EBS performance.

First -  DC RUM using agentless technology, captures network traffic between all servers and clients and as result provides you with information on performance, usage and availability details. Additionally for most popular network protocols including the ones used during communication with Oracle database, Oracle Forms servers and web servers it’s possible to use analyzers, that provides deeper performance insights. For example with Oracle Forms analyzer applied for EBS monitoring DC RUM is decoding all interactions between user and oracle forms reporting user names, form names, control names and identifying EBS module name. For Oracle Database traffic it reports performance down to single query execution including SQL, database schema and user name.  Answering your question it allows monitoring of Oracle EBS and Oracle DB simultaneously.

Second one – Enterprise Synthetic allows you to create synthetic tests for key transactions in EBS. This way for example you may track the performance of whole creating sales order transaction.

DC RUM is intended to constant, systematic application performance monitoring. However if you have it in your company it’s also perfect tool to evaluate the results of the load tests performed on EBS.

Comment: Thanku for your key inputs. But here I am again sticking on my second point - Can we monitor Concurrent processing server using DCRUM? as in EBS there are many background jobs running during any transaction which are actually handled by concurrent manager servers . Hence these servers can also have some bottlenecks which we would like to keep a track of.

Comment: If concurrent processing server is deployed on separate host you are able to monitor it with DC RUM - and you will get network performance metrics - information on network performance, connectivity, usage in bytes. Otherwise it's still possible to get the performance visibility with our java agent with Application Monitoring solution - but it will work for html UI only (not for Oracle Forms).

Comment: Thanku for further information. Can you please provide me some references so that I ll be able to see how concurrent manager servers performance metrics are monitored? As I found the oracle forms server monitoring in DCRUM documentation but didn't find any information about concurrent manager serves. ref- https://community.dynatrace.com/community/display/DCRUM122/Oracle+Forms+Monitoring
FYI
We have different hosts for concurrent manager servers.